# Nginx rewrite rule remove subfolders

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regular-expressions

I'm trying to setup a nginx rewrite rule but can't figure out how to get it working.

I want to redirect all urls https://domainname.com/archives/year/month/date/postname to https://domainname.com/postname

The page https://domainname.com/archives needs to stay active though.

Who can help me out?

Cheers, Jaap

Comment: It should be a simple regular expression. Are year, month & date all numeric? Do you want a 301 or 302 redirect?

Comment: Yes, all numeric and they should be 301.

Comment: I have posted an answer which assumes the date format is `yyyy/mm/dd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
rewrite "^/archives/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.+)$" /$1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details. [A useful resource for regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: Thanks the format is indeed yyyy/mm/dd. I've put this in a server block like this: 

server {  rewrite "^/archives/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.+)$" /$1 permanent; }

Restarted Nginx but the redirect is not working.

Comment: You need to add it to your existing server block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) on server blocks.

Comment: Yes! First added it to the wrong one. Corrected this and now it's working except for a couple of urls. Will look into that. Thanks for your quick help @richard-smith !